# Are there any potential problem using two submit buttons in the same form?

Tags: html, forms

I created a form with many sections the user can save the form using a button at the end of the form or a button that is kept in a fixed side nav. The structure is like this (with additional CCS to keep the form blocked).

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="POST" role="form">

    <div class="sidenav">
        <a> some section links</a>
        <a> some section links</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-success">SAVE</button>
        <a class="btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Leaving the page, might cause loosing the data not saved.');" href="/">Leave the page.</a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main">
        <div>
            ... a lot of stuff
        </div>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-success">SAVE</button>

</form>
```

A beta tester using Chrome told me that the button on the side nav sometimes is not working, while the one on the bottom is always working, but I can't reproduce this behaviour in my browsers or understand the causes.

Is there something I am missing? Which is the correct implementation of a form with two submit button?

Comment: Multiple submit buttons are fine. We'd need more info from your beta tester to figure out the issue

Comment: the beta tester is a bit dumb (it's totally fine to have multiple submit)

Comment: If you want to know on the server which button, give it a name and a value

Comment: @j08691thanks for your comment, yes I have asked her some more details, but we could not find what's the problem.